# Ajax file upload not working in chrome browser

Tags: ajax

I am using AjaxUpload for file upload but with the recent update in Chrome, it seems to be no longer working in chrome and many other browsers. So I started to figure it out. I have to spend around 2 to 3 hours trying various possible ways but it was not working.

The Issue was, When we select image or file then it was calling the OnComplete Event without calling server-side action due to which it was returning a null empty value. And after completed with OnComplete event then server-side action got called with no return back to OnComplete Event.

When **“iframeSrc”** is set to **“javascript:false”** on https pages, Chrome now seems to cancel the request. Changing this to **“about:blank”** seems to resolve the issue

Later I fix this in the code and it seems to be working for me now.

```
var iframe = toElement('<iframe src="about:blank;" name="' + id + '" />');
```

I hope it will work for you as well. :)

Reference: https://www.infomazeelite.com/ajax-file-upload-is-not-working-in-the-latest-chrome-version-83-0-4103-61-official-build-64-bit/

If is there anything I am missing the do correct me.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the issue.

Old Code:

```
var iframe = toElement('<iframe src="javascript:false;" name="' + id + '" />');
```

New Code with chagnes:

```
var iframe = toElement('<iframe src="about:blank;" name="' + id + '" />');
```